# Getting web API token for Google Play Games before launch

Tags: web, google-play-games

So I was going to try and implement google play games for my web / android game and while the Android side of things seems to be quite well-documented in terms of how to get everything up and running, the web API documentation, I find severely lacking.

My problem is that right now, I have my game on my server in an alpha state, something which I obviously don't want anyone other than my testers to access. Therefore I have added IP filtering to keep anyone else out of there. The problem is however that Google Play Games doesn't seem to be able to add my application and give me the API token if I don't allow it to visit the site. I might very well be wrong about that however, since I haven't actually tried to link it to any other address.

Could someone help guide me in the right direction here? Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I might have gotten some terminology wrong, but the problem I'm having looks like this, which makes me believe that it isn't possible to generate the client ID. This error appears every time I click on continue. [image: The error]

Also, if you try to go to that URL, you'll notice a 403 error, which is the IP filtering I was talking about earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by myself. I don't know if it matters, but I started by verifying my domain in Google's normal API console. After that was done, I created a new web application there (still normal API console) and then when I returned to the Play developer console, it said that I could import it from there and it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Games Services uses oAuth2.0 authentication, so there's no need for an API key. However, you are required to setup the necessary client ID which is discussed in the [Create Client IDs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) section of the documentation. Once done, [setting up your web app](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/gettingstarted) to handle authorization and calling the REST APIs will follow.